# One of my variables is being changed for no reason

Tags: p5.js

I am following The Coding Train's flappy bird challenge in p5.js. All is going well until when I try to run the program, both, "Pipes' always move up when i jump the first time. It is only the first time i hit the space bar. I have zero idea on what is happening here. The positional values of the pipes do not ever intersect with the keyPressed function, so I'm just curious on where it moving upwards is coming from.

```
let bird;
let pipes = [];
let pipe;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 600);
  bird = new Bird();
  pipe = new Pipe();
  pipes.push(new Pipe());
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  bird.update();
  bird.show();

  pipe.prints();
  for (let i = 0; i < pipes.length; i++) {
    pipe.prints();
    pipes[i].show();
    pipes[i].update();
    pipe.prints();
  }
  pipe.prints();
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (key == ' ') {
    bird.up();

}
function Bird() {
  this.x = 64;
  this.y = height / 2;

  this.gravity = 0.9;
  this.lift = -20;
  this.velocity = 0;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 32, 32);
  }

  this.up = function() {
    this.velocity += this.lift;
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.velocity += this.gravity;
    this.velocity *= 0.9;
    this.y += this.velocity;

    if (this.y > height) {
      this.y = height;
      this.velocity = 0;
    }

    if (this.y < 0) {
      this.y = 0;
      this.velocity = 0;
    }

  }

}
function Pipe() {

  this.top = random(height / 2);
  this.bottom = random(height / 2);
  this.x = width;
  this.w = 20;
  this.speed = 3;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    rect(this.x, 0, this.w, this.top);
    rect(this.x, height - this.bottom, this.w, this.bottom);
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.x -= this.speed;
  }
  this.prints = function() {
    print("Top: " + this.x + " Bottom: " + this.w);
  }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: You're missing a closing curly bracket in your `keyPressed()` function. But other than that, this code seems to work okay for me.

Comment: I'd assumed that was just from copying and pasting to here @KevinWorkman

Comment: @LukeGarrigan You're probably right, but it's important that OP posts exactly the same code they're running, otherwise this is all just guesswork.